# Unable to select value in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform project containing a `DataGridView`.

There is the column :

```
this.ColumnComboBox.FillWeight = 103.2981F;
this.ColumnComboBox.HeaderText = "Test ComboBox";
this.ColumnComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
"test1",
"test2",
"test3"});
this.ColumnComboBox.Name = "ColumnComboBox";
this.ColumnComboBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

I've try to set `ReadOnly` to false in [Design] windows but the designer always replace it by the code above.

Also, my DataGridView contains this event :

```
private void Gridview1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        // ComboBoxColumn
        case 3:
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = Gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            if (listItem[e.RowIndex] is DisplayComboClass)
            {
                comboCell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
            }
            else
            {
                comboCell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't know why but when I run my project, my DataGridView displays combobox when it's needed but I can't select a value. When I click on it, nothing happens, values "test1/2/3" doesn't appear.

Comment: Try to comment the change on Display style in your event, then check again the issue.

Comment: I've try but I still have the problem.

Comment: Does Datagridview's readonly property set to false right?

Comment: the DataGridView.ReadOnly is set to false in designer. But I'checked with the debugger, this property is set to true after the `InitializeComponent`. I suppose that a parent component force it to true, I'll try to find it

Comment: set DataGridView.ReadOnly to false after InitializeComponent.

Comment: @Berkay It works. I don't know what happened. In my designer, the default value for ReadOnly is false so it don't force it. But after `InitializeComponent` the value is true. I have create an inherited class with new property ReadOnly to watch get/set and the set is never called before my code after `InitializeComponent`. A mystery for me, but now it's ok. Thank you

Comment: your welcome, added as an answer too @A.Pissicat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
DataGridView.ReadOnly = false;
```

after `InitializeComponent()`,

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

There is other setting that also preventing the draw of the combos if
DataGridView.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
Hope helps some body.